# Hibernate, how to don't make proxy object

Tags: hibernate

I have Lazy fetch collection in hibernate. I make HQL request and don't fetch that collection. How to said hibernate don't make proxy object and don't initialize that collection, when I use it in code? I just want to get empty collection in code or `null` value.

Comment: You can't. If you don't want the collection to be loaded, then don't access it.

Comment: Main problem is that I use library for JSON serialization. And it accesses to all fields in object, include that not initialized collection. So I get **LazyInitializationException**, because session doesn't exist. I know, that I can set `null` value to not initialized collection. But it's workaround: I make proxy object for collection and then `null` it, because know, that I don't need it.

Comment: If using Jackson, add @JsonIgnore to the collection, or use a view, or use the Hibernate module and configure it to not serialize uninitialized collections. If using another JSON library, find the equivalent. In short, it's a JSON problem, not a Hibernate problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with lazy loading via the hibernate proxy object. Got around it by annotating the class having lazy loaded private properties with:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties({"hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler"})
```

I assume you can add the properties on your proxy object that breaks the `JSON` serialization to that annotation.

The problem is that entities are loaded lazy and serialization happens before they get loaded fully.

```
Hibernate.initialize(<your getter method>);
```